Strange linking problem when `dlopen` a library
I have some strange linking problem with a library which is dynamically loaded using dlopen.
Precisely, I have a code that loads a library libmine.so (which is part of the code) that depends on Intel MKL, and ldd shows correct dependencies that come from a Conda environment:
ldd build/libmine.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe921f6000)
        libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2 => <conda-env>/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so.2 (0x0000736f17e00000)
        libmkl_intel_thread.so.2 => <conda-env>/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so.2 (0x0000736f15800000)
        libmkl_core.so.2 => <conda-env>/lib/libmkl_core.so.2 (0x0000736f11400000)
        // omitted standard things for C libraries

However, in the code where this library is used, there is also embedded Julia. And this is where the problem comes: somehow the libmine.so library uses not the above Intel MKL that comes from the Conda environment, but Intel MKL from Julia, which has some problem that leads to crash due to unresolved dependencies:
INTEL oneMKL ERROR: $HOME/.julia/artifacts/be271e9c6341c97e67428ba9cad4f0a6b87d2993/lib/libmkl_sequential.so.2: undefined symbol: mkl_spblas_ccsr0nd_uc__mmout_seq.
Intel oneMKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load <mkl-thread-layer>.

Does anyone know how to fix this and how the dependencies are resolved when one uses dlopen?
I should add that the code is compiled via CMake, and uses -Wl,rpath-link flag that denotes to the Intel MKL from Conda environment, which is somehow not used in the runtime.

The problem is with FindLapack CMake module - it uses wrong linking flags to Intel MKL by default.
One can fix it by adding elegant and intuitive line
set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64_dyn)

to the CMakeLists.txt file.
